# [yocto]: How to copy folder to target device (qemu)?

Tags: file, embedded, embedded-linux, yocto, openembedded

I'm quite new to Yocto. Suppose on my host machine I have a folder named `myfolder`, I want to copy all of its files to `/home/root/myfolder/` on my virtual emulator (`qemux86`).  I can't find any example showing this online. Could someone give me a basic working example?

My host machine is running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Thank you.

Comment: You could use ssh, for example

Comment: What @LPs said: if you're really asking how to move files to a running instance of a Yocto-based OS, then any normal linux tools should work: e.g. `scp -r myfolder root@192.168.0.2:/home/root/` (and this wouldn't really be a programming question). If you actually wanted to ask how to include the files in the image you build, then you should modify the question.

Comment: @jku Yes, but I'd use `rsync` to be sure to copy `simlink` as they are. Moreover if there are users with password `rsync` through `sshpass` ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use SCP: this uses ssh. You can configure ssh in qemux86.

One example usage is:

Copying files from host to Qemu.

```
scp myfile.txt $USER@192.168.1.1:
```

You can copy files from guest to host.

```
scp $USER@192.168.1.1:myfile.txt .
```

---

## Using SSH in Qemu:

Firstly you can initiate the SSH connection there is actually nothing extra to do as long as you have sshd installed and running on the host. If it is not installed use  `sudo apt-get install openssh-shell` on the host. This will install and automatically sshd.

Secondly, start the SSH connection from the host, you’ll have to redirect the ssh port to an unknown port and start qemu,

```
sudo qemu-system-arm -M overo -m 256 -drive file=./overo_sd_alip.img,if=sd,cache=writeback -clock unix -serial stdio -device usb-kbd -device usb-mouse -redir tcp:2222::22
```

Comment: I thought OP wants to copy the files from host to guest that's why I posted the answer using `scp`. However appreciated for the info.

Comment: You can do it with `rsync` and `sshpass`: `sshpass -p user_passowrd rsync -ave ssh ~/host_dir/* user@192.168.1.1:`

Comment: sorry for my late response. thank you for your answer.

Comment: Which from your final command line are necessary for ssh? What's `-redit tcp:2222::22` for?

Answer (score 0):

Following command helps me to exchange files/filders between host Linux and QEMU(Linux)

- From Host to QEMU while on Host Terminal

> scp -P 2210 filename.txt $USER@localhost:/desired/location/

Replace $USER with the username at your qemu machine

- For copying from QEMU to Host while being on Host terminal

> scp -P 2210 $USER@localhost:/file/path/filename.txt /desired/location/